# DynamicJasper: Need columns to span only one cell in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic-jasper

Exporting a report to Excel using DynamicJasper. Some of the columns in my report span multiple columns in Excel. Need help in configuring the report so that each column in my report spans only a single column/cell in Excel.

In the screenshot below, I want src1_QUANTITY1 to span only column J, I want to make column J wider if needed but I don't it to span J & K.

[src1_QUANTITY1 spans columns J and K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo9Z4.png)

The following is the code for configuring my report:

```
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = 
    new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
configuration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
configuration.setSheetNames(new String[] { sheetName });
.......
JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
ArrayList<JasperPrint> printList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
printList.add(DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(
    this.createReport(), new ClassicLayoutManager(), params));
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(printList));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

Comment: You are using the ClassicLayoutManager which is not excel friendly. See the docs: http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-create-a-clean-excel-report/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ListLayoutManager. But the ListLayoutManager does not seem to support sub-reports. I need to layout multiple tables on a single sheet in Excel and am using ClassicLayoutManager with sub-reports for this. By changing the ClassicLayoutManager to ListLayoutManager causes the report to be empty, because internally generateJasperPrint is dependent on groups. Appreciate any pointers.